# How can i make the path to Url

Tags: php

How can i make the path to Url? example

```
$file= "home/a9449962/public_html/somedir/page.html";
function geturl($f) {
// some codes that returns the url "website.com/somedir/page.html"
}
```

Is there a function for it?

Comment: the path `echo getcwd();`

Answer (score 0):

```
$file= "home/a9449962/public_html/somedir/page.html";
function geturl($f) {
    $f = str_replace('home/a9449962/public_html/','website.com/',$f)
    return $f;
}
```

or if this path is dynamic you can use the `preg_replace()` with  an `regex`

Answer (score 0):

There is no function for that.  It assumes a web directory structure.  In reality the defined web root, symbolic links, rewrites, etc, can all influence this.  If you know this works for you then you can do a little string manipulation and be done with it, or wait for someone here to write your code for you.

You might want to look at [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variables like `REQUEST_URI` and others.